# Unir dos consultas en un foreach

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, foreach

Tengo el resultado de 2 consultas mysql, cómo podría unirlas en un foreach? Necesito imprimir en una tabla de blade las columnas de CLIENTE, COMPRAS y PAGOS. Desde ya muchas gracias!

```
[
 [{"cliente":"Juan","total_compras":"2500"},{"cliente":"Pedro","total_compras":"3400"}],
 [{"cliente":"Juan","total_pagos":"1200"},{"cliente":"Pedro","total_pagos":"3000"}]
]
```

Comment: ¿Y no podemos considerar mandar la data *unida* desde la propia consulta?, consider añadir tu consulta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doy por hecho que quieres realizar el arreglo en el lado del servidor para imprimirlo directamente en pantalla.

Por la estructura del json, creo que siempre tendrás 2 arrays con n clientes cada uno. En ese caso lo único que tienes que hacer es juntarlos (con *array_merge*) y luego recorrer el array resultante buscando por el cliente. Si el cliente no existe lo añades a un nuevo array. Si el cliente existe, añades sólo la etiqueta que te interesa:

```
$json = '[[{"cliente":"Juan","total_compras":"2500"},{"cliente":"Pedro","total_compras":"3400"}],[{"cliente":"Juan","total_pagos":"1200"},{"cliente":"Pedro","total_pagos":"3000"}]]';

$grupos_clientes = json_decode($json,true);

$datos_clientes = array_merge($grupos_clientes[0],$grupos_clientes[1]);

$nombres = [];
$datos_finales = [];
foreach($datos_clientes as $dato){
    $key = array_search($dato['cliente'],$nombres);

    if($key === FALSE){
        $nombres[] = $dato['cliente'];
        $datos_finales[] = $dato;
    }
    else{
        $datos_finales[$key]['total_pagos'] = $dato['total_pagos'];
    }
    
}

print_r($datos_finales);
```